# Cannot view Newest or Activity on Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange

A recent change to Stack Exchange has added a message to the top of the tagged sets asking if I wish to receive email updates. Since this change, I find I cannot switch the view to Newest or Activity, furthermore, the note constantly reappears.

Comment: Reproduced.  That's annoying.

Comment: If you manually remove the `subscribe` url parameter, you can change the tab.

Comment: Yes it is annoying :) I find I need to type in the sort= tab manually as well as removing the subscribe parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed.  Sorry about that -- the subscribe message at the top is only supposed to show up for certain paths, but it was getting added to the URL everywhere.